# Custom VBO action to print selected nodes

Tags: views

I would like to use views bulk operations to select and then print a large amount of nodes at once. I only want the print dialog box to open one time for the whole batch. Any ideas on how to approach this process?

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you managed to accomplish this? I've got a similar issue and am trying to figure out how to print printer-friendly versions of a bunch of nodes in bulk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [hook_action_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_action_info/7) implementation, you should set `'aggregate'` to `TRUE`. For example:

```
function YOURMODULE_action_info() {
  return array(
    'YOURMODULE_your_custom_print_action' => array(
      'type' => 'node',
      'label' => t('Print nodes'),
      'aggregate' => TRUE,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you managed to accomplish this? I've got a similar issue and am trying to figure out how to print printer-friendly versions of a bunch of nodes in bulk.

Comment: @SN_26 Actually, I didn't managed to accomplish this, I just pointed out the  `'aggregate' => TRUE,` option to apply the action on the whole batch, instead of on individual nodes. You can ask to the original poster, Eazye1977, how he managed to do this, if you want a complete code example.