# How to print nodes in bulk?

Tags: views, nodes

I have a view where I am listing all the nodes. user can select the ones he wants to print in bulk.
I am able to show the print option in VBO but I am stuck with next step as how to send all the selected nodes to print.

Can anyone help me to get this done.

Thank you

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86755/custom-vbo-action-to-print-selected-nodes